# What's the difference between Procheck and Whatcheck?

Tags: protein-structure

I'm currently using [Procheck](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/software/PROCHECK/download.html)* to check a protein backbone. The process is:

1. Determine backbone phi, psi, and omega angles
2. Compare to known angle distributions to identify outliers, and angles in disallowed regions

Is [Whatcheck](https://servicesn.mbi.ucla.edu/WHATCHECK/)** equivalent for this task?

*, checks the stereochemical quality of a protein structure, producing a number of PostScript plots analysing its overall and residue-by-residue geometry. It includes PROCHECK-NMR for checking the quality of structures solved by NMR.

**, Derived from a subset of protein verification tools from the WHATIF program (Vriend, 1990), this does extensive checking of many sterochemical parameters of the residues in the model.